# Will dwarves restack bolts in the latest edition of Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

There are tons of single bolts laying around from where my dwarves have shot things. If I reclaim them will dwarves restack them? I don't really want my dwarves running around with 1 or 2 arrows on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the current version of Dwarf Fortress, Dwarves and Adventurers do not stack things. **Ever**.

If the bolts are metal, it might be better to melt them down instead so that you will eventually recoup *some* of the metal for a new stack, because the alternative, as you yourself mention, is a dwarf running around with a 1 stack of ammunition.

Comment: I figure stacking has to be soon, giving the current mercantile focus.

Comment: @C. Ross -- myself as well. Myself as well...

Comment: A few versions ago melting down single bolts produced more metal than it took to make a single bolt. Somebody made an adamantine farm sploit farm that way.

Comment: Yup! Just another example of Dwarven Physics at work! It takes 1/25 of a bar to make a bolt (produced in stacks of 25) but melting down a single arrow gives 1/10 of a bar back. It's ingenious!

Answer (score 5):

In the latest version of Dwarf Fortress, bolts don't stack. But your dwarves will store multiple bolt items in the same quiver so they will have an adequate supply of ammunition.

The lack of stacking does mean that when you want to move bolts from A to B, it will take more hauling jobs to move the individual bolts.

Comment: Unless the bolts are binned, which they should be if in a stockpile.

Comment: Except there's a bug with bolts and bins, where after a short time dwarves seem to ignore bolts inside bins when trying to restock their quivers. It's possible that you could set up a cycle to bin them all to stack them, then remove them from bins so that military will collect them - but I think once they're 'ignored' from being binned, they stay ignored. It's weird.